# How to refer to attributes in enums?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, enums, attributes

How can I refer to attributes in `enums`?

If I have the following `enum` type, how do I refer to the attribute for a particular value of this enum type?

```
public enum PersonGender
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Male = 1,
    Female = 2,
    Intersex = 3,
    Indeterminate = 3,

    [EnumMember("Not Stated")]
    NonStated = 9,

    [EnumMember("Inadequately Described")]
    InadequatelyDescribed = 9
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should add some more info to your post, not just downvote the answers.

Comment: BTW if you are using System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute, then it should be applied this way `[EnumMember(Value = "Not Stated")]`. And you have two values equal to 9.

Comment: @user2154065 He didn't, the two first answerers downvoted each other

Comment: @ofstream No, I was the first answerer. I did not downvote anyone.

Answer (score 4):

Following code is using .Net 4.5 extension method [GetCustomAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194292.aspx) to get custom attribute of field

```
Type enumType = typeof(PersonGender);
var value = enumType.GetField(PersonGender.NonStated.ToString())
                    .GetCustomAttribute<EnumMemberAttribute>().Value; 
// returns "Not Stated"
```

Of course you should add null-checks for field and custom attribute

Comment: `Error 1 'System.Reflection.FieldInfo' does not contain a definition for 'GetCustomAttribute' and no extension method 'GetCustomAttribute' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Reflection.FieldInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @IswantoSan you are using old Framework. That is not reason for downvoting answers

Comment: I don't think so [`CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194292.aspx)

Comment: Exactly, you MUST be using an old Framework. This method exists.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Sorry, my fault, I just check again and I use .NET 4.0.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: I can't vote up the answer: Your vote is now locked in unless the answer is edited..

Comment: @IswantoSan you now can :) I added info about .Net version. And for future - don't be so impulsive with downvoting. I usually write comment to answer before actually downvoting (there is always probability that I'm wrong)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

For example:

```
    class EnumMemberAttribute : Attribute
    {
        private String name;

        public String Name
        {
            get { return this.name; }
            set { this.name = value; }
        }

        public EnumMemberAttribute(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type type = typeof(PersonGender);
            MemberInfo[] members = type.GetMember(PersonGender.NonStated.ToString());
            Object[] attributes = members[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute),
                false);
            Console.WriteLine(((EnumMemberAttribute)attributes[0]).Name);            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, set InadequatelyDescribed to another value than NonStated.

Secondly the right syntax for EnumMembers is

```
[EnumMember(Value = "Not Stated")]
```

And here is the solution - working in **.NET 4.0** as well as in 4.5:

```
PersonGender pg = PersonGender.InadequatelyDescribed;
string pgName = Enum.GetName(typeof(PersonGender), pg);

var t = typeof(PersonGender);
var info = t.GetMember(pgName);
var att = info[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute), false);

if (att.Length > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(((EnumMemberAttribute)att[0]).Value);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(pgName);
}
```